# "Unexpectedly found nil" but the value is successfully checked with "print". Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Getting an "unexpected found nil" error, but when checking the value - its there:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if whichLink == "official link" {

    let urlStr = videoGame.offLink!
    let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
    else if whichLink == "moby game link" {

        print("yo yo yo, value is here! \(videoGame.mgLink)   ")

        let urlStr1 = videoGame.mgLink!
        let url1 = NSURL(string: urlStr1)!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url1)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

    }

}
```

I'm suspecting an error in storyboard... but can't locate anything. 
Did anyone has a clue what can be wrong?

The full project can be found @ https://github.com/flostik2008/Favorite-Games

[image]

Comment: not seeing any crash

Comment: Try eliminating the space at the end of your URL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL string is incorrectly formatted with the space at the end, so the `NSURL` initialization is returning nil.

You should URL encode all raw strings before trying to create an `NSURL`:

`let urlStr1 = videoGame.mgLink!.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!` should work

Comment: daaaaamn Tom... worked like a charm. 

Thanks for a your help Tom and @andy-ibanez